# Why my components inside the map runs twice even though just before of map it runs single time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The map function produces the < PricedLayout /> component twice. I don't understand why it occurs, so I assumed that it might be because my map function was called twice, but that isn't the case since I can see a single printing of "testing" right before the map function.

```
const FreeAndMegaTestSeries = (props) => {

return (
 <div className={styles.main}>
 
  <div className={styles.right}>
    <p className={styles.mainHeading}>Mega Test Series</p>
    <Slider
      arrows={true}
      slidesToShow={3}
      slidesToScroll={2}
      autoplay={false}
      infinite={true}
      prevArrow={<img src={leftarrow} alt="left arrow" />}
      nextArrow={<img src={rightarrow} alt="right arrow" />}
    >
      {console.log("testing")}
      {props.priced.length &&
        props.priced.map((p, i) => {
          return <PricedLayout p={p} i={i}/>
        })}
    </Slider>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default FreeAndMegaTestSeries;
```

////////////////////////////PricedLaout////////////////////////

```
 const PricedLayout = (props) => {
 const p=props.p;
 const i=props.i;
return (

  <>

 <div className={styles.slider}>
   <div className={styles.container} key={i}>
     <div className={styles.enroll}>1.2k students enrolled</div>
   </div>
 </div>

  </>

);
};

export default PricedLayout;
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but your Slider component might use 2 same items for transitions. One at start and one at end. Might want to check out your Slider component documentation. the infinite prop on there seems like a good start

Comment: @SlothOverlord Oh, thank God, the issue has been resolved once I set the infinite prop on the slider to false, however may I ask why it occurred?

Comment: Probably because if you want to have an infinite slider with one element, it keeps adding the copy of it at the end so you can slide it. As I said, it is best to check the docs of that npm package to see how infinite works. You are mapping only one component, but the package makes another one inisde. If you had 3 elements inside the map, the infinite will make it so you have 4 if you inspect the elements of your page